# Construction of non measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

In explanation of non measurable sets we take $Q_1$=Q $\cap$ [-1,1](Q is set of rational numbers).Then we define equivalence relation on [0,1].
x,y $\epsilon$ [0,1] as x~y iff x-y $\epsilon$ $Q_1$. This equivalence relation introduces a partition on [0,1] splitting [0,1] into mutually disjoint classes $E_\alpha$.
Then [0,1] = $\cup E_\alpha$.
Then it is said each element of $E_\alpha$ is rational. How can each element of $E_\alpha$ be rational. What will happen to irrational numbers of [0,1].

Comment: Didn't you post this earlier today, and now you have deleted it, instead of editing it, Mohammed?

Comment: "Then it is said each element of $E_{\alpha}$ is rational." Really? Who is it that says that?

Comment: I am curious as to the advantage of using $Q_1$ rather than $\mathbb Q$ in "$x \sim y$ iff $x-y \in Q_1$" ?

Comment: It's given in MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS VOLUME TWO BY SOMASUNDARAM

Comment: If it really says that, then throw that book out, quick!

Comment: Also, if you want me to see a comment, please put @Gerry in it, that way I get notified.

Comment: See if $E_\alpha$ are not rational then whether $E_\alpha$ will contain irrational numbers also. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Yes, if the elements of $E_{\alpha}$ are not all rational, then by definition $E_{\alpha}$ will contain irrational numbers. What is your point?

Answer (score 4):

To start, it should read:
$$
Q_1 = \mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1]
$$
The intersection of the interval with the rationals, ie. only the rationals from -1 to 1.

Then as Haagexa said, the elements in $E_\alpha$ are not all rational, they have rational **differences**. So, for instance, $\frac{\pi}{12}$ and $\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{1}{100}$ are both irrational, but they have a rational difference $(\frac{1}{100})$ so they belong to the same set $E_\alpha$.

Comment: What is Haagexxa

Comment: Haagexa posted an answer, but then deleted it.